# How to select a variable in a React component using Jest, Enzyme or @testing-library/react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I need to check if there are any variables in App.js and then check their type. I checked all the docs for *jest*, *enzyme* and *react testing library* but found nothing useful.

If anyone can give me a hand it'll be very much appreaciated. Sharing my code below.

**App.js:**

```
  const names = ["George", "Lewis", "Max", "Charles", "Fernando"];
  const surnames = ["Pedrosa", "Rossi", "Crivillé", "Márquez", "Lorenzo"];

  return <div className="App"></div>;
}

export default App;
```

**Test:**

```
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import Test from "../../block02/ex02/src/App.js";
import { screen, render } from "@testing-library/react";

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe("b2ex02: Display name and surname side by side", () => {
  it("Declare two arrays", () => {
    // here I need to select the "names" and "surnames" variables and check that they are typeof array
  });
});
```

If I can provide any other useful piece of information I will be happy to. Thanks!

**Edit**

I fully recommend testing variable existence through some kind of using them. Otherwise this has proven imposible to achieve.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I don't think you're going to find an answer in those docs. Those arrays are implementation details, and libraries are going to make it hard for you to test them. What is the behavior those variables demonstrate that you could test?

Comment: @JakeWorth I work in a school and we're making tests for the first react exercises. They are supposed to pass these arrays to components. I'm checking props.children with enzyme and checking type. I think we can also check the props of the ones that have type Component for a variable named `names` or `surnames`

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. I think it's not easy to do because they are implementation details, rather than end-user functionality.

Comment: We ended up testing changes behavior more than the existance of those variables. Per example, you cannot check state for functional components, so instead of that we check initial value and then change the state and check the value again. Thanks for the help tho!